# How can I make my app running also in Doze mode without Partial_Wakelock?

Tags: android, android-wake-lock, android-doze

I wonder; How can we our App work in Doze Mode without using Partial_Wakelock? or without high battery usage ?

Comment: asking `how do X and Y achieve this` won't find you answers - we don't work for those companies, we don't know how their software works. you're better off asking `how do i achieve X` but you'll first have to show you've done some research and attempted something first

Comment: @a_local_nobody now I'm editing question..

Comment: Your question cannot be answered as is. More info and code ```snippets``` from your project are needed. Please refer to how to ask a good question to make your question eligible for SO: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask